# How to vertical center suffix of TextFormField?

Tags: flutter, flutter-textformfield

[image]

[image]

```
TextFormField(
      keyboardType: textInputType,
      inputFormatters:
          isCodeField == false && state != null && state!.code == 'UZ'
              ? [maskFormatter]
              : null,
      obscureText: isCodeField,
      style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
      textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 7, horizontal: 7),
        border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4)),
        prefix: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 6),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: prefixRow ?? [],
          ),
        ),
        suffix: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 6),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: suffixRow ?? [],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

I tried `contentPadding` , `textAlignVertical` , wrapped my suffix widget with `Padding` , used `suffixIcon` , but couldn't center my widget.

Answer (score 0):

In Suffix Padding, provide padding from top as well

```
TextFormField(
              style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
              textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 7, left: 7),
                border:
                    OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4)),
                suffix: const Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 6, top: 6),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: [Icon(Icons.remove_red_eye)],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

[image: Output]